# Women and Kriyas Hatorah

Tags: torah-reading, women

Are women responsible to hear Kriyas Hatorah?

Comment: What does "responsible" mean?

Comment: Are Chayav to hear.

Comment: Glad we've cleared that up then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Magen Avrham** (אור"ח סימן רפ"ב) says based on **Masechtas Soferim** that even though they are not responsible for learning Torah **Women are responsible to for Kriyas Hatorah**.Then he adds even so woman are not careful with it and some even leave on purpose during Kriyas Hatorah. The **Maharsham** (בשו"ת מהרשם ח"א  סימן קנ"ח) asks on this how is it possible seeing that you cant learn the written Torah at night it becomes a Mitzvah that is  a time bound Mitzvah (**מצוה שהזמן גרמה**)and therefore women should not be responsible? He answers that a Mitzvah even though it is time bound that is of rabbinical origin women are responsible as it says in Rashi in the Gemara Brachos on Chuf amud Beis. Another possible answer is since at ceartin times you are allowed to learn written Torah at night like thursday night so it is not a real time bound Mitzvah.